# HTML Parsing: Get elements between two elements?

Tags: python, xpath

I'm parsing with lxml on Python 2.7

I have some html that looks like this:

```
  <tr height="45" valign="bottom">
    <td colspan="2" class="DATE">Wednesday, Aug  5 2015 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>       </td>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td/>
    <td> - No Calendar Matters Currently Set<br/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="45" valign="bottom">
    <td colspan="2" class="DATE">Thursday, Aug  6 2015 </td>
  </tr>
```

Is there any way for me to get a list of all `td` element objects in between the two elements of `class="DATE"`?

Basically, I need all the info associated with, say Aug 5, but since the other elements before the next date aren't children I'm struggling to figure out how to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as want: all elements with td[@class="DATE"] ahead and before

```
//td[following::td[@class="DATE"] and preceding::td[@class="DATE"]]
```

but this set will not contain td tags with @class="DATE"

To include them use xpath

```
//td[(following::td[@class="DATE"] and preceding::td[@class="DATE"]) or @class="DATE"]
```